# UTF8 problems when using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I know this has been asked before. But I have exhausted the options given in the answers I can find, so I will ask again and hopefully there is something I have overlooked.

First of all, my files are UTF8-encoded and my XML header (I am using XHTML) declares the page to be UTF8.

Secondly, the first thing I do after connecting to the database is sending the query "SET NAMES utf8".

I have also executed this statement: "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%'" and have set all those variables to utf8.

I have executed SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name on each and every table involved and I have made sure that their character set is utf8.

When I look at the values in the database it looks like UTF8-encoding, with codes beginning with &. This does not feel right, I don't know why they are stored like this. I did try to echo them out on my page with PHP's utf8_decode but this did not work.

What more can I do?

(If my problem is not clear from the title, characters such as ä å and ö do not show up properly in browsers.)

Comment: This sounds like a php issue. What is your PHP character encoding set to?

Comment: http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/charsets#php_s_problem_with_character_encoding this may give you some insight

Comment: When you say they "do not show up properly", what do you mean? What appears instead? Have you been using the steps you describe since day 1, or have you implemented them only recently, after already having stored text containing these characters in the database? (Text that was already stored before you took steps to handle non-ascii characters correctly may be stored mis-encoded.)

Comment: "Not correctly" means nonsense characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. This was a PHP issue, as was suggested, and it was derived from my faulty use of htmlentities instead of htmlspecialchars. Be ware when using those functions and utf8 characters! htmlspecialchars is the one you probably want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` ?

Answer (score 0):

When you insert stuff to database, run it through `utf8_decode()` and when you take the result out of database, run it through `utf8_encode()`.

Also make sure you have UTF-8 encoding or auto detect selected in your browser encoding settings.

Comment: Really? If you think it will help, I will try it, but it makes not sense considering the db is supposed to be in utf8?

Comment: What is the exact collation of your table?

Comment: The tables are UTF8 (as in if you do SHOW CREATE TABLE on it, default character set = utf8). I don't know how to find the exact collation, nor what it means.